# Differed values in unix

Tags: unix, compare, difference

I have string like this

```
A=00000 1 001055 37 002001 279
B=00000 1 001045 65 004060 23
```

How to compare and print differed values?

I am expecting output as
Differed

```
 values = 001055 37 002001 279
          001045 65 004060 23
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What have you searched ? What fails ? How ? Need some more infos

Comment: I used if clause ..but it checking string is correct or not...I want to print differed values between two strings

Comment: There's not enough information here. For instance, your example shows the non-unique portions occupying exactly the same position and number of characters in both strings. Will that _always_ be the case? If so, identifying and removing those parts will be more straight-forward and quite different from how you would do it otherwise.

Comment: Yes that's the case...non unique portions occupying exactly the same position and number of characters in both strings

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What is expected before posting question is listed here [ask] and here [mcve].